# Missing Drivers in Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I just got a new PC with an Asus H410M-A. Windows 10 installed most of the drivers by itself and everything seems to be working but when I looked at device manager there were some missing drivers... So I went to asus website and downloaded the chipset drivers package and installed it.

Now I still have 2 devices with missing drivers (see screenshot - It's in Italian):

[image: Device Manager]

Where else should I look for those?

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked Windows Update -> Optional Updates -> Driver Updates.  Device drives are distributed through Windows Update not device manager in newer versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Please kindly check if the following article was helpful to you: [How to Find Hidden and Missing Drivers with Windows Device Manager](https://windowstechies.com/how-to-find-hidden-and-missing-drivers-with-windows-device-manager/)

Comment: @Ramhound that solved my issue. If you want to write a proper answer I will mark the question as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I went to the Asus website and downloaded the chipset drivers package and installed it.

Drive updates are now installed through Windows Update.

[image]